# How to programmatically import an XML export file into a Caché installation?

Tags: java, intersystems-cache

The situation is as follows:

- I have an XML export of a project;
- I have a working Caché installation (which means I have `cachedb.jar` and `cachejdbc.jar`);
- I have a namespace/user/pass to work with.

What I want to do is:

- import the XML into this namespace;
- collect the list of classes imported by that XML;
- write the plain source files in a destination directory;
- remove the imported classes after I'm done reading.

I know how to do point 3 (using class [`%Compiler.UDL.TextServices`](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25Compiler.UDL.TextServices)); but I have no idea how to do point 1.

Also, it may be that the Caché installation *is not* on the machine on which I want to do the import.

So, what class can I use to import that XML, and how do I specifically retrieve the classes which I have just imported, and not the others?

---

**EDIT**: OK, it appears that what I must use is [the `LoadStream` method from `%System.OBJ`](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25SYSTEM.OBJ#METHOD_LoadStream).

Given a `Database` object, it means I can run it as a class method using the `.runClassMethod()` on this object... Except that I fail to see how to create the stream in the first place. Argh.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [$System.OBJ.Load](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25SYSTEM.OBJ#METHOD_Load) method and pass him the XML file name to import and possibly compile files.Use `loadedlist` argument to get a list of imported items.

To remove imported classes first call [$System.OBJ.UnCompile](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25SYSTEM.OBJ#METHOD_UnCompile) method, and after that delete class definitions from [%Dictionary.ClassDefinition](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25Dictionary.ClassDefinition) class.

Comment: The problem with this method is that the file is required to be on the same machine that the Caché installation is; I don't want that restriction :/

Comment: Okay, why don't you create stream in java and call LoadStream  method?

Comment: http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=BLJV_using#BLJV_using_streams

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the idea I'm trying to figure out how to code at the moment... Thanks for the link!

Comment: Also, uhm, do you have to compile before you can write back using %Compiler.UDL.TextServices?

Comment: loading will be enough, compile does not needed

Answer (score 0):

Answer to self: [it's done, and it's on Github](https://github.com/litesolutions/cachedb-import).

There are still problems though.